# Is "R" and "res" the same in Android projects?

Tags: android

I keep on seeing references to R, which I've read is the resources, and I see a "res" directory in an Android project. Are they the same?

Comment: R is the reference of all the res contents, not exactly the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, R is only a class in Java automatically generated to **represent** the "res" directory and its resources.

In other words when programming, you'll need to refer to R when you need to access the resources located in the "res" folder.

Answer (score 3):

No, R is a automatically generated class with the definitions for the resources you define in your xml files. Res is the resources folder which has all the drawables (images), layouts, menus, strings, among other things.